# Resizing button on PDF page pinch

Tags: ios

I am developing pdf application in iPhone. I am loading PDF page on view and UIview is on UIScrollView.

On pdf page i am adding custom button. Now i want to resize button on pdf page pinch. PDF pinch cause only resize button but . currently my PDF page is also resizing along with button.

So how to resize button on PDF page pinch?

Any help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you're adding everything on the UIScrollView. You want to add your button to a different view layer that's on top of UIScrollView, but not within. This is a bit more complex, as you need to change the object position on every position/zoom change of the scrollview - but there are enough delegates so that this can be achieved pretty easy.